# Do I need a license to use the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: discussion, api, licensing

I recently developed an App for Stack Overflow using the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).

This app is only for fun and I want to add code in Github.

Do I need to add a licence for using the Stack Exchange API?

Comment: see: http://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use & http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not really. You have the [Terms of Use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use), which is actually enough.

From the ToS:

> By using or accessing the API Services, you agree to become bound by all the terms and conditions of this API Agreement as well as the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

So that is your license. You, as a user of the service, have to comply to the ToS, including rules about attribution, etc.